# What is the best tool for pen testing android app

Tags: android, penetration-testing, penetration-tools

What is the best tool for pen testing android app? I want to connect the device to my PC, launch the app in my android device, execute different functions of the app and pen test the app using pen testing tools in my PC. I don't want to use any kind of emulator. What is the best approach to pen test in this way? Can I do it in Kali Linux platform? Any kind of suggestion for tools or anything would be helpful.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First learn about adb commands for connect the device to your PC. So that you can launch app in your device. Yes you can use Kali linux.
Then go for these tools,

1. [BurpSuite](https://portswigger.net/burp/download.html) Pro (for proxy intercept , etc)
2. Drozer
3. dex2jar
4. [AppWatch](https://appwatch.io/) by Attify.com
5. [AndroBugs](https://github.com/AndroBugs/AndroBugs_Framework)
6. [MobSF](https://github.com/ajinabraham/Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF)
7. [JD-Gui](https://github.com/java-decompiler/jd-gui) (for analyzing source code)
8. apktool

Each tool has its own specialty.

These are the latest tools you can use for android penetration testing

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for opensource tool to audit your android app go for [Mobisf](https://github.com/ajinabraham/Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to answer question but there are unlimited tools you could use, it totally depends for which purpose etc.
see few tools I like to use below

- APKInspector:
- Androrat
- Droidbox
- zaNTI
- Dsploit

Regards

Daniel